# JBOSS CLI commands to drop/delete values from domain.xml file

Tags: linux, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, jboss-cli

Does JBoss CLI have advanced CLI commands using which we can drop/delete contents of domain.xml and host-slave.xml files?

My use-case is , whenever there is a new release to my application , there are changes that happen to these two files. If there are JBoss CLI commands to achieve this, I can incorporate the appropriate CLI commands in to the orchestration tool to implement JBoss related changes to the application

The version of JBoss is 7.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there are: jboss-cli is the preferred way to update the configuration as opposed to editing the XML files by hand.

Comment: Thanks, Can you help me with some sample command by which I can edit/delete the contents of domain.xml and host-slave.xml file?

Comment: https://docs.wildfly.org/20/Admin_Guide.html#CLI_Recipes